# Can i use MAMP (MySQL) or XAMPP (MySQL) with Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xampp, mamp

Can i use MAMP (MySQL) or XAMPP (MySQL) with Ruby on Rails 3? i installed MySQL from MYSQL.com and had so much trouble that i like to use the MAMP/XAMPP Mysql. Is Anyone doing this? Also what configurations do i need to make to do this. I'm new to RoR.

Thank you in advance ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I use it, this is  my config in database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: app
  username: app_user
  password: app_password
  socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
```

I'm not sure if it's the only thing to changed, you maybe must to copy MySQL header files from the source of MySQL and put it in the MAMP directory

Comment: more info here: http://www.eleven33.com/2010/10/ruby-on-rails-install-with-mamp-on-os-x/

Comment: I am having same issue, but mysql is in xampp in windows, so can you tell me that what will socket path in mycase, I think this is only thing wrong in my configurations.