# Connect to MySQL using Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im currently working with ruby on rails, which is an area that I'm entirely new to. I'm using MAMP and have set up a local MySQL database called `my_db` with a table called `employees` `https://localhost/phpmyadmin`.

Is there a way to connect to this database using ruby on rails and write to this table in the database. I have tried many examples but all of them show you how to connect to a mySQL db installed natively. I can't seem to work out how to connect to a database that lives in MAMP. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, if phpmyadmin can connect, so can any other app. You just have to specify correct host/port/username/password and possibly other bits of info.

Comment: phpMyAdmin lives in MAMP

Comment: So? It's on the same machine, isn't it?

Comment: its an older post, but check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836094/can-i-use-mamp-mysql-or-xampp-mysql-with-ruby-on-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

Rails connects to whatever's defined in `config/database.yml`, so you should be able to connect in much the same way any PHP code does:

```
development:
  driver: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: my_username
  password: my_password
  database: my_database_name
```

Generally you connect over `host` with an optional `port` parameter.

Comment: Really? There must be a simpler way such as: 
db = Mysql.new('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_db')

Comment: The easier way is to do it through ActiveRecord, that's how 95% of Rails apps do it. You really do not want to use the low-level driver directly. An alternative is to use [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) if you need something more flexible.